# Importing root certificate on Windows CE and Windows Mobile devices via command line

Tags: c#, certificate, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I need to install a new root certificate on about 300 networked Windows CE and Windows Mobile 6.0 devices.

This can me manually done by going into the Control Panel -> Certificates -> Import

However i cannot find a way to do this via the command line. Full windows systems contain a program called certmgr.exe. I cannot find an equilevant CE or Windows Mobile.

The C# namespace doesnt have any import method and i cannot execute the certificate file as it is not a registered file extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A registry dump of

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Comm\Security\SystemCertificates\Root]`

on a machine where you've imported the certificate can be used.

Source: http://hsm.force.com/publickb/articles/HSM_Article/How-to-renew-the-GlobalSign-Root-CA-Certificate